# How can I view the video coming in from a capture card on Windows in full screen?

Tags: windows, webcam, video-capture

Question:

Is there a "standard" way to view the raw feed coming from a capture device in windows?

My goal is to be able to watch TV on my HTPC coming in through an hdmi capture card.

Background:

I bought a usb hdmi capture card. I thought it would be trivial to just view the video coming in through the card, but I can't figure it out.

VLC comes the closest to what I want: You can open the capture device and view the video in full screen. However, the playback is slow and choppy.

Native Windows 10 Camera does a decent job, except you can't view full screen -- I'm stuck with all the chrome from the Camera application.

I can find lots of webcam/video streaming software that seem to do a much better job than VLC at showing the video, but its the same problem as above: I can't remove any of the chrome from the software.

Is there a "standard" way to view the raw feed coming from a capture device in windows? I have some vague memory of being able to open up a webcam from "Devices and Printers" from Windows XP, but no such luck anymore.

Comment: You already found the standard option as capture cards are unexpected. There should also be software for said capture card that likely does what you want. You already did mention VLC as well. You likely "just" need to tweak the settings to get streaming going without stuttering. Unless your card is having issues or the sender.

Comment: @Seth the capture card shows up as a Webcam, a device that is ubiquitous on modern laptops, so I didn't think it was unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Found out that viewing in a browser is an easy way to do it. This quick html page shows the video in Chrome and allows full screen with no app chrome.

*video.html*

```
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement" controls height="540" width="960">
    </video>
</div>
<script>
    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
            .then(function (stream) {
                document.querySelector("#videoElement").srcObject = stream;
            });
    }
</script>
```

- [source](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm)
- [API doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: Follow up: bought a Hauppauge coax to usb card that actually comes with software and is a much better htpc solution